# Please help me with my dictation. He's British

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, listening

[very short, only voice, British](https://voca.ro/1GhveVCT6RO)

I'm hearing...

A: doing that blah blah 45?

B: that's plenty of time

I'm watching a British cooking show program

Situation is, there's three people in a team and

one of the team members, cooking on his own, said he's gonna speed things up.

And then the other team members said that kind of thing to him, observing what he's doing.

Because they got 1 hour and 45 minutes.

I want to know what A's saying

I'm only sure about "45" .... lol

Comment: Sounds to me like "Put a number 45" but it's tough to say what that might mean without context.

Comment: Pretty sure its "I've got another 45". The "I" is almost a grunt, and the "t" in "got" is a glottal stop.

Comment: They are both talking at the same time. Personally I hear : so now we're (at?) 45, ... And I also hear the other guy saying : that's easy. Not too sure about the "plenty of time " you are hearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two people speaking over each other, but the main speaker is saying:

> "He's got an hour 45, that's plenty of time."

"An hour 45" is just an informal way of saying "an hour and 45 minutes".